# I have simulated this constant current circuit on Lt-Spice, why do I get so low values for current output?

Tags: voltage, current, amplifier, resistors, ltspice

I used a Howlands current pump inspired model using two op-amps, and my goal is to get a constant current output for load resistance range of 500-3000 ohms. The circuit I found uses A PWL voltage source. However for a load-resistance of 3000 I only get about 3mA current output. my university professor got about 30mA just by changing the resistor values,  how? I have attached a picture of the schematic. [image: schematic]

the website I used as reference where I got the schematic can be found here:https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-design-a-precision-current-pump-with-op-amps/

Answer (score 4):

You have given your op-amps supply potentials of 0V and +9V. These are the upper and lower limits of output potential that U1 can produce. With a load of \$10\Omega + 3000\Omega\$, the greatest current that U1 can produce through R6 is \$\frac{9V}{3010\Omega}=3mA\$, and that's why you never see more than that.

If you wish to get more output current, then you either have to increase the op-amp's supply potential, or reduce R6. With an op-amp supply of \$V_{CC}\$, you can't ever have more than \$I_{OUT(MAX)}\approx\frac{V_{CC}}{R_6}\$.

Remember also that most normal op-amps will struggle to output much over ±10mA, so even if you did change \$V_{CC}\$ or \$R_6\$, there's still no guarantee you'll actually get 30mA.

The article states that given the condition \$R_2 = R_3\$ and \$R_4 = R_5\$, then:

$$ I_{OUT} = V_{IN} \frac{R_4}{R_1R_2} $$

In your circuit, \$ R_4 \ne R_5\$; they are very slightly different. It's close enough, though, to get an estimate of the kind of current you can expect given a certain input. The input to the circuit in your case is a differential voltage, \$V_{IN}=V_3-V_2\$.

Your PWL source \$V_3\$ goes from 0V (at time t=0) to 0.5V (at t=100ms), and \$V_2\$ is constant at 0.25V. Therefore \$V_{IN}\$ goes from \$0V-0.25V=-0.25V\$ to \$0.5V-0.25V=+0.25V\$. Plugging in these values for \$V_{IN}\$ yields these values for \$I_{OUT}\$:

$$ I_{OUT}(t=0) = -0.25V \frac{1k\Omega}{10\Omega \times 50k\Omega} = -500\mu A $$

$$ I_{OUT}(t=100ms) = +0.25V \frac{1k\Omega}{10\Omega \times 50k\Omega} = +500\mu A $$

Obviously this won't be what you see in the simulation, since \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ are not equal, but with an input of ±0.25V you won't achieve the currents you expected.

---

Here's a unipolar current voltage-controlled sink that will do what you need (according to the comments so far):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fABMEr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This employs an om-amp with 100% negative feedback to ensure that the voltage across R1 is equal to \$V_{IN}\$. The resulting current through R1 is drawn via the load, RL:

$$ I_{OUT} = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} $$

[image]

This design does not require the op-amp itself to produce high voltage output, but instead relies on MOSFET M1 to do the heavy lifting. M1 needs to be a high voltage device, able to tolerate \$V_{DS}=100V\$.

This requires two supply sources, +100V and +9V. The 100V source can be derived from the +9V source using a DC-DC boost converter.

MOSFET M1 will dissipate a maximum power of \$50V\times 15mA = 1W\$. It will get quite hot, and I would recommend a small heat-sink for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am a Mech student and this is the first time I am dealing with an electrical engineering project. so from my understanding I need a supply  potential of 93V? I thought the op-amps produce an output voltage greater than the voltage difference they receive.So in theory what changes do I need to make in the circuit values , to achieve a current of 30mA for a load resistance of 3000ohms?

Comment: @IraklisArma \$V=IR=30mA\times 3000\Omega=90V\$. Yes. You'll either need a very special op-amp, or some kind of buffer to achieve that. There are alternative approaches that would probably be more appropriate. Do you need current in both directions, or just one?

Comment: @IraklisArma Also, does it matter if the load is connected to ground or not? Things get a lot simpler if one side of the load is connected to the high voltage positive supply, and current through it is modulated by varying voltage on the lower potential side.

Comment: current should travel in both directions as I need biphasic waves. the aim of the circuit it to mimic an electrical stimulator that has electrodes connect to human skin , to provide that amount to current through. The load mimics the body skin resistance. So I assume I should keep it connected to ground. Hope that helps

Comment: sorry , I was wrong on my previous comment. Current should trackel in one direction. Essentially my constraints are the 9V power supply and the I need an outcome current of 30mA. V3 is used as a Dc signal.

Comment: @IraklisArma You simply can't get 30mA through 3000Ω without a supply under 90V. So, if you only have 9V, you need a boost converter to produce over 90V, and capable of 30mA or more.

Comment: I see. can a boost up converter be found as a single component on LT-spice or does a whole other circuit need to be remade? also you previously mentioned a buffer?

Comment: also you mentioned what the use and role of U1 is. What is the use of U2. in this circuit?

Comment: @IraklisArma You would usually build a boost converter as an independent circuit module, and treat it as a voltage source, as you would a battery or power supply. U1 is a [differential amplifier](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-8/building-a-differential-amplifier/) "doing the math", but is slightly modified. Usually R5 sinks current to ground, but here it must sink to a different potential. U2 provides that potential, while still sinking current to ground instead of deriving that current from U1's output. It's a buffer providing a "copy" of the required potential.

Comment: @IraklisArma I've described another design that might work for you, in my anwser.

Comment: Thank you for the schematic! For a DC-DC  boost converter I found the "Microchip MCP1650R-E/MS, Boost Converter, Step Up 100mA, 850 kHz 8-Pin, MSOP" that boosts 5.5V to 100V. Can this component be simulated?

Comment: @IraklisArma I don't know, sorry. I find with DC-DC converters simulation doesn't help much anyway. Most problems arise from parasitic inductance and resistance due to layout problems, which simulators can't spot. You can emulate it using a 100V DC source with another sawtooth source in series with it, representing high frequency (850kHz in your case) ripple. You'll need the datasheet to find an estimate for ripple amplitude. My advice would be to build the converter, and assess its performance under various loads, with an oscilloscope.