# For this circuit, how can I produce a current output of 30mA?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistors

For this circuit, how can I produce a current output of 30mA? R6 acts as a load. The voltage power source of the op amps has to stay 9V and R6 at 3000. I understand that Iout= VCC/R6+R1, therefore VCC has to be 90V, but I thought by setting the op amps this way and just by changing the values of the resistors, we can achieve 30mA for a load resistance of 3000ohms.
[image]

Comment: It is impossible o get 30mA across 3kΩ ohms resistor if Vcc = 9V. You can't get around Ohm's law  3kΩ*30mA = 90V.

Comment: Seems very similar to your [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/674497/330261).

Comment: sorry for repeating myself. So is there any components that increase a 9V battery up to 90v?

Comment: What do you want ti achieve or make? What "real world device" represent this 3kΩ ohms resistor?

Comment: it represents the human skin impedance. This is for my university project. I am making a low current low frequency Tens machine.

Comment: My project supervisor suggested that my range of resistance should be between 500-3000 ohms. Also he is claiming he manage to get that same circuit to produce up to 72V output, just by changing the resistor values

Comment: @IraklisArma Do you have to follow that exact schematic? Or can you use the original 2-opamp improved Howland found in its original public release by Philbrick in 1964 (Philbrick worked with Howland at MIT's Lincoln Laboratory and Howland never wanted to patent or copyright the idea.) Or another improved Howland written up by Bob Pease and now found in a TI publication?

Comment: I don't have to follow that exact schematic but have to use 9v as my power source and 3000 as my load resistance

Comment: I thought from my really limited knowledge that using that schematic with the two op amps we can get voltage output higher than the input power supply voltage

Comment: @IraklisArma You think wrong. You have a ground-referenced load and your absolute requirement is that you achieve 30 mA into it. At 500 Ohms, this requires 15 V. At 3k Ohms, this requires 90 V. There's no getting around this. It's physics. Different universe? Maybe. Just not the one we have, though. Note that this required voltage has to be presented at the (+) input of U4. There are no opamps I know of that can be powered on a single 9 V rail and survive 90 V at an input pin.

Comment: I think I just found out how my professor managed to get those values... he used a universal op amp1 , I assume that doesn't represent reality to the slightest?

Comment: @IraklisArma Not in the slightest.

Comment: @IraklisArma So he gives you an impossible task and just lets you twist in the wind about it? He hates you that much? Maybe you are supposed to realize the impossibility and he's willing to just let you suffer until you work it out on your own that you were played? If so, that's a lesson you won't soon forget.

Comment: You want to pump 30 mA through human skin? Of a live specimen?

Comment: XY problem. No way you are going to be pushing 30 mA though a patient.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously homework and you are supposed to work your own way through it. So I'll keep it more about education than a direct answer, per se.

First. I'm just going to say it... You can't get \$90\:\text{V}\$ if all you have is \$9\:\text{V}\$ to work with. Not in this circuit. Not without adding some kind of voltage-boosting mechanism. And even assuming you could mysteriously achieve \$90\:\text{V}\$ over the load, \$U_4\$ wouldn't survive.

[image]

There's also the question about what you are supposed to be doing: *"I am making a low current low frequency Tens machine"* (from comments you've added.)

From my own review of the literature on TENS (which you should do or else should have done, already), I find that voltages up to \$350\:\text{V}\$ are considered to be within reason for such a device. They are inherently *battery powered* and many of them do, it seems, use a standard \$9\:\text{V}\$ alkaline battery for this purpose.

This means a few tentative conclusions arrive:

1. \$9\:\text{V}\$ alkaline battery is common and appropriate. Do not change this requirement.
2. The ability to generate much higher voltages is also required due to varying skin contact resistances that may be encountered.
3. Although professional units can achieve peak voltages of \$350\:\text{V}\$, the instructions you received for using \$3\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$30\:\text{mA}\$, indicating a peak of \$90\:\text{V}\$, may have been appropriately modest. So I can't find fault there.
4. The assignment obviously requires you to figure out the need for, and the design and production of, a voltage boosting circuit. This is something you could have worked out in the beginning from a very simple "sanity check" calculation and the idea that voltages don't magically increase by themselves.
5. The need for a voltage booster also indicates some caution with respect to the idea of using opamps, which often cannot stand off nearly as much voltage as you appear to have been assigned to handle. This may suggest further study of the idea of adding discrete, external active devices to support the more common opamps that are otherwise unable to handle these voltages.
6. The need for a voltage booster also indicates some careful thought with respect to a Howland current source. However, I'm not entirely sure that a Howland current source is necessary. This suggests further study, as well.

   There are other means of voltage-controlled current circuits that operate at high voltages and that can be operated using an AC control voltage (if desired.) I'm not convinced that a precision current source is required here, from what little I've read. And you seem to suggest in comments that you are not stuck with the presented schematic.

   So this door appears open to me.

This is the kind of *ideal* project were I looking to hire from an *inexperienced* design engineer pool (entry level job.) It's sufficiently simple that I could reasonably propose that a candidate stand at a chalk board and show me their thinking. And it is just complex enough that I would be able to observe important parts of their thinking process that I'd need to see in order to risk my time and money on them for the next year.

Since I'm getting more into the history of things, I'd like to add a couple of things worth reading:

- [Bob Pease's writing on Howland, as captured by a TI appnote](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf?ts=1689798172349&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). Bob provides a little historical tidbit in this document about Dr. Howland (circa 1962) and the individual who published it, Dr. Philbrick (in 1964.)

  *(I still am baffled by how often I'm now finding large electronics businesses like TI feeling perfectly comfortable taking the writing of Bob Pease, put it into an appnote, and then strip accreditation. It's simply wrong and I'm never going to accept it as anything other than uncontrolled, rampant plagiarism. Which is what it is and there's nothing they can say or do to convince me otherwise. It's evil. It's disgusting. And it is where we seem to be today.)*
- [The original publication that carried Dr. Philbrick's disclosure](https://www.philbrickarchive.org/1964-1_v12_no1_the_lightning_empiricist.htm).

(Use the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) should either of these links become broken.)

Here's a picture (Figure 5b) from the 2nd link above:

[image]

The above schematic (as I copied it out) needs a clarification. There is a blemish of some kind on a feedback resistor for the upper right opamp, labeled as what might be read as **K R**. This is actually **K Ro**, like the other nearby resistors that are more clearly labeled as **K Ro**. If you look closely, you'll see a very tiny mark/blemish by the **R** on that resistor. It really should be **K Ro** and not **K R**. Analysis would unearth this fact.

Speaking of which, here's a way of analyzing the circuit shown above and disclosed in 1964. I labeled the output node of the lower left opamp as ***eo1*** and for the output node of the upper right opamp as **eo2** (they also have associated output currents labeled as ***io1*** and ***io2***, respectively.) I labeled the (-) input node of the lower left opamp as ***em1*** and the (-) input node of the upper right opamp as ***em2***. Finally the node over load impedance **Z** is labaled as ***ez***. With that in hand:

```
rz,io1,io2,k,ez,e1,e2,r,ro,eo1,eo2,em1,em2 = 
      symbols('rz,io1,io2,k,ez,e1,e2,r,ro,eo1,eo2,em1,em2',real=True)
e1 = Eq(em1/(ro+r)+em1/(ro+r)+em1/ro,ez/ro+e1/(r+ro)+eo1/(r+ro))     # KCL for EM1.
e2 = Eq(em2/k/ro+em2/k/ro+em2/k/ro,eo2/k/ro+e2/k/ro+eo1/k/ro)        # KCL for EM2.
e3 = Eq(eo1/(r+ro)+eo1/k/ro,io1+em2/k/ro+em1/(r+ro))                 # KCL for EO1.
e4 = Eq(eo2/k/ro+eo2/r,io2+em2/k/ro+ez/r)                            # KCL for EO2.
e5 = Eq(ez/rz+ez/ro+ez/r,eo2/r+em1/ro)                               # KCL for EZ.
solve([e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,Eq(em1,0),Eq(em2,0)],[ez,em1,em2,eo1,eo2,io1,io2])
{ez: (e1*rz - e2*rz)/r,
 em1: 0,
 em2: 0,
 eo1: (-e1*r*ro - e1*r*rz - e1*ro*rz + e2*r*rz + e2*ro*rz)/(r*ro),
 eo2: (e1*r*ro + e1*r*rz + e1*ro*rz - e2*r*ro - e2*r*rz - e2*ro*rz)/(r*ro),
 io1: (-e1*k*r*ro**2 - e1*k*r*ro*rz - e1*k*ro**2*rz - e1*r**2*ro - e1*r**2*rz - e1*r*ro**2 - 2*e1*r*ro*rz - e1*ro**2*rz + e2*k*r*ro*rz + e2*k*ro**2*rz + e2*r**2*rz + 2*e2*r*ro*rz + e2*ro**2*rz)/(k*r**2*ro**2 + k*r*ro**3),
 io2: (e1*k*ro**2 + e1*k*ro*rz + e1*r*ro + e1*r*rz + e1*ro*rz - e2*k*ro**2 - e2*k*ro*rz - e2*r*ro - e2*r*rz - e2*ro*rz)/(k*r*ro**2)}
```

Take note that \$e_z = \frac{r_z}{r}\left(e_1 - e_2\right)\$ and that therefore \$i_z=\frac{e_1 - e_2}{r}\$. Which is the point of the device.

Comment: ill try make sense of the code, and thank you for the information, as I am really bound by time due to the submission, even though I understand your comments about the neccessity of Howland current source, ideally I want to modify my scematicwitha step up converter to get those Voltage ranges

Comment: @IraklisArma Understood. Best wishes.

Comment: @IraklisArma As you move forward with speed, keep in mind the need for either high voltage opamps with unusual output current capabilities (good luck there) or else external active components. This won't be easy all by itself. Yet another issue.